# is it possible to deploy c# mvc 5 with mysql database online

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment

So i'm developing a project using c# mvc5 with mysql database.
I currently deploy my project in my local IIS. i also use xampp for my database 
is it okay to have that set up or there will be a problem when i deploy it online

Comment: XAMP is not for production. Use a new installation of mysql instead. Of course you also need a Owin Host/IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be an issue at all. You just have to make sure when you publish it online you need to provide it with the correct connection details.

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you have any suggestion on where can i host it ?

Comment: There are plenty of hosts out there. It comes down to your requirements and how much you can afford. 
You can spin up your VM on any cloud provider or use any managed databases providers

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run a database that the production server can reach (could be on the same machine) and you will have to run the C# code in some way, but without more information about that I cant really say more about the production env, if its a windows server running IIS you could run it pretty much exactly as you do on the dev server.

Your development and production environments could look very different and it should not really affect the production environment in the end, but its always a good idea to run the development and production environment as similar as possible.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i just wondering if there will be a problem deploying it online.  Do you have any suggestion on where can i host it.?

Comment: When it comes to C# I would first of all suggest checking out [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com) because its pretty much built for it. There are other options too, especially if you run dotnet core, but azure should be a good fit.